# Chart information depends each datagrid row

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, row, charts

I want to have a chart on each row of a data grid, being that the chart source information is information o the row the chart is inserted into.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="idCampaign" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="idPerson" HeaderText="idPerson" Visible="false"
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idPerson" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="age" HeaderText="age" SortExpression="age" />   
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
               <Series>
                  <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="name" 
                                    YValueMembers="age"></asp:Series>
                  </Series>
                  <ChartAreas>
                     <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                  </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:outboundsmsConnectionString %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT idPerson, name, age FROM Person WHERE (idPerson = **currentRowPersonId**)">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I'm having quite some trouble with this and don't know how to get the bold part...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SelectCommand='SELECT idPerson, name, age FROM Person WHERE (idPerson = <%# Eval("idPerson") %>)'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that results on the following string:

'SELECT idPerson, name, age FROM Person WHERE (idPerson = '

If I remove the previous string part from the selectCommand the idPerson is shown

Answer (score 1):

Chad's sugestion worked but with a little twist:

```
SelectCommand='<%# Eval("idPerson", "SELECT idPerson, name, age FROM Person WHERE (idPerson = {0}") %>)'
```

Thanks!